# Take Rails app offline during deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, passenger

I was just wondering if there something similar to [`App_Offline.htm`](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/06/426755.aspx) (it cuts all dynamic requests to the app and returns a static page) in Rails/Passenger/Capistrano to?

I am looking for the following flow when deploying to the server:

1. Pull the source code.
2. **Take the app offline.**
3. Backup the database and (maybe some other stuff).
4. Symlink everything.
5. Run migrations.
6. Minimise JS/CSS and do other processing.
7. Restart the server.
8. **Take the app back online** (revert step 2).

All is pretty easy with capistrano, except taking app offline and getting it back.

I could probably come up with a **Rack** application that could be plugged in when I need to take the app offline, but just wondering maybe such rack app **already exists** or maybe there is a **better way** of doing it?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails App Maintenence Without Hindering Visitors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361656/rails-app-maintenence-without-hindering-visitors)

Comment: Yes. It is very similar, but I was looking for something that does not require Apache/Nginx config changes. Pure ruby would be best.

Comment: That's probably going to be your only option. If you're updating your rails app, the rails daemon will be down for a short period.  The only thing remaining up to serve a maintenance page is going to be Apache, Nginx, or whatever web server you're using.

Comment: Makes sense. Who knows what's going to happen with Ruby while doing all the weird deployments :)

Thanks guys for finding the duplicate - I could not see it initially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes a bit of configuration in your web server, but Capistrano makes this pretty easy.

[Capistrano to deploy rails application - how to handle long migrations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244263/capistrano-to-deploy-rails-application-how-to-handle-long-migrations)

Comment: Thanks. But I guess you could just vote to close the question instead of answering by providing link to the other answer. We should also have *close duplicate answer* on SO :)